# Facebook Logout Script

Tags: selenium

Can you please let me know how we can logout in chrome browser by using selenium?

e.g

```
public class AJ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://facebook.com");
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        element.sendKeys("user@example.com");
        element=driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
        element.sendKeys("password");

        element.submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code should help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://facebook.com");
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    element.sendKeys("user@example.com");
    element=driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
    element.sendKeys("password");

    element.submit();

    //Click on dropdown menu then logout button
    driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("logout_form")).click();

    //Check to see if email login box is available 
    //therefore confirming user has logged out
    driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
}
```

I recommend using the Chrome Developer tools to help you find unique attributes of a page for Selenium to find.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In python the same is done using this line of code. It uses the same module i.e, Selenium.
So just change the element using css selector by using the argument passed below.

```
logout1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._w0d[action='https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?button_name=logout&button_location=settings']").submit()
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to successfully logout from Facebook.

**Here is the Java code**

String url = "http://facebook.com";

```
    String email = "email";
    String password = "password";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/chromedriver 3");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");


    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get(url);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Your email here");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Your password here" + Keys.ENTER);
    driver.findElement(By.id("logoutMenu")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[contains(@id,'show_me_how_logout')]/../../../..")).click();
```